# Settnig the LayoutParams for the first parent view?

Tags: android

Here is my xmls (there are basically two views: a linear [`B`] inside a relative [`A`])

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/A"
android:layout_width= "wrap_content"
android:layout_height= "wrap_content" >

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/B"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
</LinearLayout>

</<RelativeLayout>
```

I need to set the `RelativeLayout`'s params but I have no idea what class it should belonged to (since it is parentless).

```
SomethingLayout.LayoutParams p = new SomethingLayout.LayoutParams(w*10, h);
A.setLayoutParams(p);
```

It would be great if someone can tell me how this can be done.

---

The reason why I need to do that is because I want to set the width of `B` as 10 times of the screen width, namely `w*10`:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams para = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(w*10, h);
B.setLayoutParams(para);
```

When I animate `B`,

```
ObjectAnimator animation2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(B, "x", -w)
```

it shows that the width of `B` is `w` rather than `w*10`, as if `A`, who is being the parent view, is limiting its width.

And therefore I figured out that setting A's params can solve the problem. But I have no idea how to do that...

Answer (score 0):

If you invoke the method "setContentView(R.layout.A);" in your activity.
The parents'type of A maybe Framelayout.

You can code like below:

```
setContentView(R.layout.A);
ViewGroup p = (ViewGroup) A.getParent();
if(p instanceof FrameLayout){
FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(w*10, h);
    A.setLayoutParams(p);
}
```

I'm a Chinese , my English is not very good, so please forgive me if I make any grammatical mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

See if something like this works for you

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams para = B.getLayoutParams();
para.width = w*10;
para.height = h;
B.setLayoutParams(para);
```